# The table "accounts" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have several tables that I want to encrypt. For each column I create another column to hold the encrypted value. The column type is varbinary(256). This worked without any problem.

During the debugging process, I decrypted the table and drop those columns. I repeat the store procedure that created the columns and encrypted the values. After a few times creating and dropping those columns I get maximum size exceeds warning. The columns are created and data is encrypted without problem. If I drop the table and recreate it, it is fine for another several iterations. **I have tried this with several tables with different definitions with the same result.**

It seem if a column added and dropped there is something left in the table. Shrinking the database and DBCC CLEANTABLE did not help.

What's happening and how this can resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14998/11574

Comment: Thanks AaronLS. ALTER TABLE REBUILD solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop a column in sql server, it isn't actually dropped - the bits(pages) are just marked as dead and will not be reused.

this little example will show you

```
set nocount on
create table dbo.mytable (bigcolumn nvarchar(3500))
insert into dbo.mytable (bigcolumn) values (replicate('x',3500))
go 50

exec sp_spaceused mytable

--name      rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
--mytable   50      464 KB      400 KB  16 KB       48 KB

alter table dbo.mytable add bigcolumntoo nvarchar(3500)

exec sp_spaceused mytable
-- you will see the table size is still the same (as we havent populated the new column)
--name      rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
--mytable   50      464 KB      400 KB  16 KB       48 KB

-- lets drop the original column

alter table dbo.mytable drop column bigcolumn

--check the size of the table and you will see it is still the same 

exec sp_spaceused mytable

--name      rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
--mytable   50      464 KB      400 KB  16 KB       48 KB
```

if you login with a dedicated admin connection then you will be able to track down and find the objects (your columns) in the base tables.  It is worthwhile noting this is also the case with things like default constraints.

if you want to avoid this then you will just have to redesign your solution.

Hope this helps